# Navigation type in WebView

Tags: android, uiwebview, android-webview

In IOS we use

```
navigationType==UIWebViewNavigationTypeBackForward||
navigationType==UIWebViewNavigationTypeFormSubmitted||
navigationType==UIWebViewNavigationTypeReload in (BOOL)
webView:(UIWebView *)webView 
shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request 
navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

How to do the same in Android `onPageStarted`?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Android WebView doesn't explicitly expose information about the cause for a navigation.

I guess, you want to know that because you expect your page to initiate navigations via JavaScript? (Because obviously you should be able to track yourself navigations initiated from your app via WebView Java API).

There are some ad-hoc tricks you can apply:

- for checking back / forward navigations you can query `WebBackForwardList` via `WebView.copyBackForwardList`, and check for the changes in its state;
- for form submissions, you can check the request method in `WebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest` (available since API level 21);
- reloads are the trickiest ones -- the best you can do is to use `WebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading` to get notified about navigations, and store the previous URL somewhere.

Comment: how to detect link click in andriod webview??

Comment: Use `WebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading`